# Dropdown with trash buttom to delete the item from the list

Tags: listview, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, dropdown, bootstrap-5

I Lokking for some solution to make this kind of dropdown, there should be a list of items and also a trash button to remove one of the item. I was looking in bootstrap and kendo and didnt fint nothing. Anny help?[image]

Comment: Use templates([combobox](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox/configuration/template) or [dropdown](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/configuration/template)) and some css to add that icon to each item.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Angular so when I tryed to make a dropdown, I have the trash button on the same line but, when I clicked trash button I also click the Item button

Comment: <kendo-dropdownbutton [data]="savedFilters" fillMode="flat" (itemClick)="selectFilters.emit($event.filters)">
                    {{ 'Filtry' | translate }}
                    <ng-template kendoDropDownButtonItemTemplate let-dataItem class="float right">
                        <span>{{ dataItem.name }}<button type="button" class="text-danger k-icon k-i-close" kendoButton fillMode="solid" icon="trash" | translate" (click)="openSelectedDeleteFilter(filtersSavedList)"></button></span>
                    </ng-template>

Comment: so I have to separete trush button from the item

Comment: Try [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in the event or `return false`. It should prevent the click to activate the button action.